# jquery number compare

Tags: jquery

I met a trouble to compare number in jquery. test code here:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var val1 = $("#aaa").attr('title');
    var val2 = $("#bbb").html();
    if(val1>=val2){
        $("#ccc").html(val1);
    }else{
        $("#ccc").html(val2);
    }
});
</script>
<div id="aaa" title="1">aaa</div>
//set title=1 show 1, set title=2 show 111
<div id="bbb">111</div>
<div id="ccc"></div>
```

As code show, two number from html dom. now I set number in `div#aaa[title]`, if set number one, it is right, and if set number 2, the result is wrong. Where is the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are comparing strings, convert them to int with `parseInt(value, 10);`

```
var val1 = parseInt($("#aaa").attr('title'), 10);
var val2 = parseInt($("#bbb").html(), 10);
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to compare `int` values, not a strings

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var val1 = parseInt($("#aaa").attr('title'));
    var val2 = parseInt($("#bbb").html());
    if(val1>=val2){
        $("#ccc").html(val1);
    }else{
        $("#ccc").html(val2);
    }
});
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/BCKKr/